# Python Pandas : Change rows and headers

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have the following array :

```
[['fic10', {'bulle_naif': '55'}, {'bulle_bool': '52'}, {'bulle_opt': '39'}, {'selection': '45'}, {'insertion': '20'}, {'rapide': '60'}], ['fic100', {'bulle_naif': '5050'}, {'bulle_bool': '5050'}, {'bulle_opt': '4816'}, {'selection': '4950'}, {'insertion': '2221'}, {'rapide': '6697'}], ['fic1000', {'bulle_naif': '2623195'}, {'bulle_bool': '1789209'}, {'bulle_opt': '2618499'}, {'selection': '2620905'}, {'insertion': '1535788'}, {'rapide': '1323294'}], ['fic10000', {'bulle_naif': '4764881010'}, {'bulle_bool': '926117379'}, {'bulle_opt': '4764749559'}, {'selection': '4764783390'}, {'insertion': '900955079'}, {'rapide': '506697139'}]]
```

And I convert it to a dataframe.

Here is what i get when i convert the array to a dataframe:

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdMg3.png)

But I would like to format my data frame like this:

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BULPd.png)

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: I suggest editing your question to include the code where you converted the array to a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's present your data in a way that's more easily understood by `pandas.DataFrame`.

### First method: a dict with one entry `key:list` per column

The goal of this method is to rearrange your data so it looks like a single dict, with one entry per column, and a list of values for each column:

```py
# {'bulle_naif': ['55', '5050', '2623195', '4764881010'],
#  'bulle_bool': ['52', '5050', '1789209', '926117379'],
#  'bulle_opt': ['39', '4816', '2618499', '4764749559'],
#  'selection': ['45', '4950', '2620905', '4764783390'],
#  'insertion': ['20', '2221', '1535788', '900955079'],
#  'rapide': ['60', '6697', '1323294', '506697139'],
#  'name': ['fic10', 'fic100', 'fic1000', 'fic10000']}
```

Here is the code to make that transformation:

```py
import pandas as pd

raw_data = [['fic10', {'bulle_naif': '55'}, {'bulle_bool': '52'}, {'bulle_opt': '39'}, {'selection': '45'}, {'insertion': '20'}, {'rapide': '60'}], ['fic100', {'bulle_naif': '5050'}, {'bulle_bool': '5050'}, {'bulle_opt': '4816'}, {'selection': '4950'}, {'insertion': '2221'}, {'rapide': '6697'}], ['fic1000', {'bulle_naif': '2623195'}, {'bulle_bool': '1789209'}, {'bulle_opt': '2618499'}, {'selection': '2620905'}, {'insertion': '1535788'}, {'rapide': '1323294'}], ['fic10000', {'bulle_naif': '4764881010'}, {'bulle_bool': '926117379'}, {'bulle_opt': '4764749559'}, {'selection': '4764783390'}, {'insertion': '900955079'}, {'rapide': '506697139'}]]

cleaned_data = { k: [] for d in raw_data[0][1:] for k in d.keys() }
cleaned_data['name'] = []
for row in raw_data:
    cleaned_data['name'].append(row[0])
    for d in row[1:]:
        for k,v in d.items():
            cleaned_data[k].append(v)

print(cleaned_data)
# {'bulle_naif': ['55', '5050', '2623195', '4764881010'],
#  'bulle_bool': ['52', '5050', '1789209', '926117379'],
#  'bulle_opt': ['39', '4816', '2618499', '4764749559'],
#  'selection': ['45', '4950', '2620905', '4764783390'],
#  'insertion': ['20', '2221', '1535788', '900955079'],
#  'rapide': ['60', '6697', '1323294', '506697139'],
#  'name': ['fic10', 'fic100', 'fic1000', 'fic10000']}


# IMPORTANT NOTE
# This cleaning-up is a bit careless
# If a key is missing in one of the lists, the resulting data will be misaligned

# Making sure data is not misaligned:
assert(all(len(l) == len(cleaned_data['name']) for l in cleaned_data.values()))

good_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(cleaned_data).set_index('name')
print(good_dataframe)

#           bulle_naif bulle_bool   bulle_opt   selection  insertion     rapide
# name                                                                         
# fic10             55         52          39          45         20         60
# fic100          5050       5050        4816        4950       2221       6697
# fic1000      2623195    1789209     2618499     2620905    1535788    1323294
# fic10000  4764881010  926117379  4764749559  4764783390  900955079  506697139
```

### Second method: a 2d array without keys but in order

If your data is already sorted so that `bulle_naif`, `bulle_opt`, etc, are already in the same order of every row, then you can get rid of all the dicts and provide `pandas.DataFrame` with a 2d array directly:

```py
# assumes the rows of raw_data are all in the same order already
array_data = [[row[0]] + [v for d in row[1:] for v in d.values()] for row in raw_data]

print(array_data)
# [['fic10', '55', '52', '39', '45', '20', '60'],
#  ['fic100', '5050', '5050', '4816', '4950', '2221', '6697'],
#  ['fic1000', '2623195', '1789209', '2618499', '2620905', '1535788', '1323294'],
#  ['fic10000', '4764881010', '926117379', '4764749559', '4764783390', '900955079', '506697139']]

keys = ['name'] + [k for d in raw_data[0][1:] for k in d.keys()]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(array_data, columns = keys).set_index('name')

print(dataframe)
#           bulle_naif bulle_bool   bulle_opt   selection  insertion     rapide
# name                                                                         
# fic10             55         52          39          45         20         60
# fic100          5050       5050        4816        4950       2221       6697
# fic1000      2623195    1789209     2618499     2620905    1535788    1323294
# fic10000  4764881010  926117379  4764749559  4764783390  900955079  506697139
```

If you don't know that all the rows are already presented in the same order, you will have to sort them explicitly to make sure:

```py
# I shuffled the entries in raw_data
raw_data = [
 ['fic10', {'bulle_bool': '52'}, {'bulle_naif': '55'}, {'selection': '45'}, {'insertion': '20'}, {'rapide': '60'}, {'bulle_opt': '39'}],
 ['fic100', {'bulle_opt': '4816'}, {'bulle_naif': '5050'}, {'insertion': '2221'}, {'selection': '4950'}, {'rapide': '6697'}, {'bulle_bool': '5050'}],
 ['fic1000', {'bulle_opt': '2618499'}, {'selection': '2620905'}, {'insertion': '1535788'}, {'bulle_bool': '1789209'}, {'rapide': '1323294'}, {'bulle_naif': '2623195'}],
 ['fic10000', {'selection': '4764783390'}, {'bulle_opt': '4764749559'}, {'bulle_bool': '926117379'}, {'bulle_naif': '4764881010'}, {'insertion': '900955079'}, {'rapide': '506697139'}]]

array_data = [[row[0]] + [v for d in sorted(row[1:], key=lambda d: next(iter(d.keys()))) for v in d.values()] for row in raw_data]

print(array_data)
# [['fic10', '52', '55', '39', '20', '60', '45'],
#  ['fic100', '5050', '5050', '4816', '2221', '6697', '4950'],
#  ['fic1000', '1789209', '2623195', '2618499', '1535788', '1323294', '2620905'],
#  ['fic10000', '926117379', '4764881010', '4764749559', '900955079', '506697139', '4764783390']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !
Can I put the name column as index of my dataframe ?

Comment: @Y0yor Yup, using `.set_index`. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Y0yor I edited my answer with a simpler method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your dataframe creation is the way the array is sorted. we need to rearrange the array in order to create the desired dataframe.

This code creates two lists in the right format for the dataframe:

```
# create empty list for cols and rows
row_names = []
cols = []

# loop over the array
for i in arr:
    # add row name
    row_names.append((i[0]))
    # create dict for row values
    new_dict = {}
    # loop over row values
    for j in i[1:]:
        # add each value to new dict
        new_dict.update(j)
    # add row dict to columns
    cols.append(new_dict)
```

When running this we will get

```
row_names = ['fic10', 'fic100', 'fic1000', 'fic10000']
cols = [
    {'bulle_naif': '55', 'bulle_bool': '52', 'bulle_opt': '39', 'selection': '45', 'insertion': '20', 'rapide': '60'}, 
    {'bulle_naif': '5050', 'bulle_bool': '5050', 'bulle_opt': '4816', 'selection': '4950', 'insertion': '2221', 'rapide': '6697'}, 
    {'bulle_naif': '2623195', 'bulle_bool': '1789209', 'bulle_opt': '2618499', 'selection': '2620905', 'insertion': '1535788', 'rapide': '1323294'}, 
    {'bulle_naif': '4764881010', 'bulle_bool': '926117379', 'bulle_opt': '4764749559', 'selection': '4764783390', 'insertion': '900955079', 'rapide': '506697139'}
]
```

This can easily be converted to the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(cols, index=row_names)
```

So all together:

```
import pandas as pd


arr = [['fic10', {'bulle_naif': '55'}, {'bulle_bool': '52'}, {'bulle_opt': '39'}, {'selection': '45'}, {'insertion': '20'}, {'rapide': '60'}], ['fic100', {'bulle_naif': '5050'}, {'bulle_bool': '5050'}, {'bulle_opt': '4816'}, {'selection': '4950'}, {'insertion': '2221'}, {'rapide': '6697'}], ['fic1000', {'bulle_naif': '2623195'}, {'bulle_bool': '1789209'}, {'bulle_opt': '2618499'}, {'selection': '2620905'}, {'insertion': '1535788'}, {'rapide': '1323294'}], ['fic10000', {'bulle_naif': '4764881010'}, {'bulle_bool': '926117379'}, {'bulle_opt': '4764749559'}, {'selection': '4764783390'}, {'insertion': '900955079'}, {'rapide': '506697139'}]]

# create empty list for cols and rows
row_names = []
cols = []

# loop over the array
for i in arr:
    # add row name
    row_names.append((i[0]))
    # create dict for row values
    new_dict = {}
    # loop over row values
    for j in i[1:]:
        # add each value to new dict
        new_dict.update(j)
    # add row dict to columns
    cols.append(new_dict)
# creta DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(cols, index=row_names)
```

Output:

```
          bulle_naif bulle_bool   bulle_opt   selection  insertion
fic10             55         52          39          45         20
fic100          5050       5050        4816        4950       2221
fic1000      2623195    1789209     2618499     2620905    1535788
fic10000  4764881010  926117379  4764749559  4764783390  900955079
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simpler and easy to understand piece of code and may it help you to solve your problem.

```
import pandas as pd

array = [['fic10', {'bulle_naif': '55'}, {'bulle_bool': '52'}, {'bulle_opt': '39'}, {'selection': '45'}, {'insertion': '20'}, {'rapide': '60'}],
         ['fic100', {'bulle_naif': '5050'}, {'bulle_bool': '5050'}, {'bulle_opt': '4816'}, {'selection': '4950'}, {'insertion': '2221'}, {'rapide': '6697'}],
         ['fic1000', {'bulle_naif': '2623195'}, {'bulle_bool': '1789209'}, {'bulle_opt': '2618499'}, {'selection': '2620905'}, {'insertion': '1535788'}, {'rapide': '1323294'}],
         ['fic10000', {'bulle_naif': '4764881010'}, {'bulle_bool': '926117379'}, {'bulle_opt': '4764749559'}, {'selection': '4764783390'}, {'insertion': '900955079'}, {'rapide': '506697139'}]]

dt = pd.DataFrame()
for item in array:
    tmp = pd.DataFrame(index=[item[0]])
    for i in range(len(item)-1):
        if i != 0:
            for key, value in item[i].items():
                tmp[key] = value
    dt = dt.append(tmp)
print(dt)
```

Output:

```
          bulle_naif bulle_bool   bulle_opt   selection  insertion
fic10             55         52          39          45         20
fic100          5050       5050        4816        4950       2221
fic1000      2623195    1789209     2618499     2620905    1535788
fic10000  4764881010  926117379  4764749559  4764783390  900955079
```